# Angular Material Design: $mdMedia('gt-md') not working in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I've been coding a project in AngularJS to start learning the framework, currently I'm using the angular-material library and I'm trying to implement a sidenav similar to their demo here: https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.sidenav

Unfortunately the $mdMedia('gt-md') call within the html below is always returning false (I'm opening it on a laptop screen so it should be true) but if I log the return from $mdMedia('gt-md') in the relevant angular controller it returns true.

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')">
```

Can anyone shed any light on why I'm seeing this behaviour? I've been struggling with it for a number of days now.

Comment: I think your laptop has a large screen so it does not trigger the $mdMedia('gt-md'), and when you are debugging it using somethink like chrome debugger or something else, the width of your screen is reduce and this method return true. You can try to reduce the size of your browser manually instead of run it in full screen mode

Comment: Laptop has a standard 15 inch screen so I don't think it's that,  also that doesn't explain why I receive true when I make the same call in javascript but false if I make it in the html?

Comment: It's not possible to answer that with so little info, but there is a strikingly similar [issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2341) answered on GitHub.

Comment: Ha I'm actually just looking at the exact same issue just now on Github! I'm not adding the service to the $rootScope so will try that later and report back.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the link posted by @ExpertSystem adding the $mdMedia service to the $rootscope allowed me to use $mdMedia directly from my HTML code.

The problem arose because as $mdMedia is a service it is not available to the view unless it is available on the scope.

Thanks all for your help!!

Comment: Keep in mind that `sidenav`'s `md-is-locked-open` is a special case, because `ngMaterial` itself makes `$mdMedia` available for the expression in `md-is-locked-open`. But if you want to use it else where, you need to make it available on the scope. And of course for the predefined constants (sm, md, lg) you can use the `hide/show-[gt-]-xx` attributes.

Comment: I didn't get it quickly. For who also don't:
You basically inject the $rootScope and $mdMedia service in your controller (that has to be in, some way, parent of the element which will use the $mdMedia). Then, inside the controller, make `$rootScope.$mdMedia = $mdMedia`. This will allow you to use $mdMedia alone in your HTML.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using "angular-material": "0.8.1" or below in yr project. Change above code to this

```
<md-sidenav 
  class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" 
  md-component-id="left"
  md-is-locked-open="$media('gt-md')">
```

Comment: Using 0.8.2 so unfortunately it's not this, I think it might be because I haven't added the service to the $rootScope as mentioned in that Github issue linked by @ExpertSystem earlier. I'll report back when I get a chance to try that fix out.

Comment: Well that actually solved my issue; thanks.. now to upgrade to newest material version